# what is the alternative in kotlin of (auto complete when I use new in android java )

Tags: android, kotlin

I am try to implement `seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener()`

In Java, I just write `new` keyword and auto-complete help me implementation and know which interface I have to Implement

is there any way like this in kotlin 
or I have to remember all of these Interfaces

I know there is no new keyword in kotlin , but I asked about how after I write object auto complete take place

Comment: I think Question is about  how to get preference intellisense which is provided by `Ctrl+Space` in java code ... All the answer below does not fulfill it ..

Answer (score 6):

The shortcut you are looking for is **Ctrl + Shift + Space**

Comment: I known why, it's because the system input method shortcut conflict with it.If someone meet the same problem, should check the Code Complete - SmartType shortcut in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, use "object" keyword to implement an interface.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {

            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `object` to implement an interface.

```
// Set a SeekBar change listener
        seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
                // Do something

            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                // Do something

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                // Do something

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no key word new in kotlin, just don't use it .
You have to use `object :` to override anonymous inner classes

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            }

        })
```

See Docs  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin doesn't contain **new** keyword. So yes, according to your dilemma it's *pain is the neck*. But it does provide you auto-complete!

All you've to do is make **object** of particular interface and then it generates you error about not implementing methods from that & then by using command `Alt+Enter` you can implement all methods from that interface.

In your case just type:

```
seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {})
```

Which will show you compilation error at **object** keyword.

---

If your interface is having single method implementation, you can directly use **Sam-constructor implementation**. I.e. for click listeners in Kotlin provides you direct autocomplete from suggestions something like :

```
view.setOnClickListener { 
    //This is the same click listener we used to implement in our Java code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after writed your object listener, for example;

`(object:ApiCallback<JSONObject>{})`

and put your cursor to above **object**, you'll see import method after make option+enter combination

(option+enter shurtcut valid for macbook keyboard, if you use windows u have to find another solution that have show listener implementation methods.